# Django models for multiple apps

Tags: django, django-models

I am making my way from RoR to Django and am making a a site with two main parts - one with 'User' management and another with 'Resource' management.

As far as I understand, these two will be defined as separate apps (in RoR would have been separate controllers). In Django the default seems to be that each app has a separate model.

How can I use the same model for these two sections? Must I define them as separate apps or can I use the same model for both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem confused.

A model is a class that equates (more or less) to a database table. An app is a collection of models, views and templates. You can have more than one model in an app. If your code is all highly related, then it belongs in one app. If you have more than one area of focus in your code, you should probably have more than one app, although this isn't a requirement.

If you want to use a model from one app in another, just import it.

Comment: Thanks - so how would I structure the equivalent to RoR multiple controllers using a single model?